# How to Submit dbms_job to begin at 06:00 and run every hour, Monday

Tags: oracle, intervals, dbms-job

how can i set interval for dbms_job that  to begin at 06:00 and run every hour, Monday.

```
X NUMBER:=1102745;    
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.INTERVAL
  (X,
   'next_day(SYSDATE,''MONDAY'')+1/24'
   );
END;
```

But this code working every on monday 01:00.

Comment: What do you mean by "begin at 06:00 and run every hour"?

Comment: on monday 06:00 , 07:00,08:00 ......23:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modern `SCHEDULER JOB` instead of old (and [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/appendix_a.htm#ADMIN11002)) DBMS_JOB

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
       job_name        => 'X'
      ,start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP
      ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;BYHOUR=06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0;BYDAY=Mon'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => ...
      ,job_action      => ...
    );
```

You can verify the repeat interval with this:

```
DECLARE
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..50 LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=HOURLY;BYHOUR=06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0;BYDAY=Mon', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( next_run_date );
    END LOOP;
END;
```